# Style display equals to 'block' is not working

Tags: javascript

My code is fetching data from an external API, but my output appears before I click on the button. It appears with NaN values. When I write number in an input field, it calculates real number and everything is fine, but ideally I would not like to see an output before I click.

When I do:

```
document.querySelector(".output").style.display = "none";
```

before the function and I do

```
document.querySelector(".output").style.display = "block";
```

in the function, I don't see anything before, but I also don't see anything after I call the function with the click on the button. Why is this happening?

```
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const input = document.getElementById("currency");

button.addEventListener("click", currencyConverter);

document.querySelector(".output").style.display = "none";

async function currencyConverter() {
  const url = `https://api.frankfurter.app/latest?amount=${input.value}&from=EUR&to=USD,CAD,AUD,CHF,GBP`;

  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);

  document.querySelector(".output").style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `
    <div class='usa'>
    <h2>USD</h2> <img src='usd.svg' height='40'> <h2>${(
      (input.value * data.rates.USD) /
      input.value
    ).toFixed(2)}</h2>
    </div>
...
currencyConverter();
```

etc...

Comment: You have `currencyConverter();` at the end of your code, does it means you called it? If you called it, that function will be called before clicking your button

Comment: Wow, that simple! Thank you very much, I knew I did something stupid, but didn't think it was this, thank you once again :)

Comment: You're welcome :D

Comment: @VanTho feel free to add your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `currencyConverter();` at the end of your code, so your function will be executed before clicking your button. If you remove that line of code, your function will works fine. 
Hopes this helps!